# How to prevent PanoramaItem from swiping to the right in windows phone 8 xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am making an tutorial page in XAML for Windows Phone 8 app. This tutorial is build with PanoramaItems. The problem is that users can swipe to the right and finish the tutorial whitout following the tutorial. I want to prevent this. This is what i got so far:

```
private void FirstItem_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        initialpoint = e.ManipulationOrigin;
    }

 private void FirstItem_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        Point currentPosition = e.ManipulationOrigin;
        if(currentPosition.X > initialpoint.X)
        {
            // Block swipe or set item back
        }
    }
```

I know that they've swipet to the right, but how can i block this?

Comment: Set panorama selected index to zero if panorama current selected index is your last index on panorama selection changed event.

Comment: How can i set the selected index? mainPanorama.SelectedIndex only gets and you can't set.

Comment: yes you can but in a tricky way set panorama's default item just like mainPanorama.DefaultItem=mainPanoram.Items[index];

Comment: Thanks for you response, but this still doesn't work. Because the page is allready loaded so it doesn't matter what defaultitem is.

Comment: So how did you solve that the manipulationdelta event does not interfere with the panorama swiping?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Panorama_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //set bool tutorial_not_finished = true once tutorial is finished, false otherwise
    if (tutorial_not_finished && ((Panorama)sender).SelectedIndex == 3) //or whatever page count you have
        panoramaControl.DefaultItem = panoramaControl.Items[2]; //some else index than last
        //or you can use "panoramaControl.DefaultItem = Item2" where Item2 is the Name in appropriate PanoramaItem in xaml
}
```

Don't have Visual Studio available right now so can't test this, but should be close enough.

Comment: Sorry, seems you got it first. Post it as answer and I'll remove mine.